# check if a group variables are equal to each other in an if statement condition

Tags: c++, variables, if-statement

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    cout << "starting program" << endl;
    for (int a=1; a<10; a++)
    {
        for (int b=1; b<10; b++)
        {
        for (int c=1; c<10; c++)
        {
        for (int d=1; d<10; d++)
        {
        for (int e=1; e<10; e++)
        {
        for (int f=1; f<10; f++)
        {
        for (int g=1; g<10; g++)
        {
        for (int h=1; h<10; h++)
        {
        for (int i=1; i<10; i++)
        if (a+(13 * b / c) +d +(12 * e )- f - 11 + (g * h / i) - 10 == 66)
        {
            cout << a << b << c << d << e << f << g << h << i << endl ;
        }
    }
    }
    }
    }
    }
    }
    }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So I have this code that finds every possible combinations between 1 and 9 to see which one will solve the equation, and as you can see I have 9 variables.

This equation can be solved in many many different combinations, however what I am aiming for is to have the variables not equal to one another. Of course I could approach this by writing each one of the conditions in the `if` statement conditions but that would be 81 conditions to put and that's a lot and stupid. Is there any way to approach this in a smarter way?

By the way, I am a beginner so if you have any advanced methods to offer, please explain it briefly.

Comment: If you check to see if the variables solve the equation, why not just fill them in into the equation and check if the result is what you want?

Comment: The problem can be solved easily with backtracking. My advice is to wait until you reach that course or try on your own to learn backtracking. Other than that there isn't much you can do right now.

Comment: btw. I like you you indented the first 2 `for`s and then you were like "Ah... screw this"

Comment: lol no that was a copy and paste error long story but i usually indent them properly and all

Comment: Sentences. Begin and end.  Full stops in between. Use them. Now about the problem. You have 9 variables. They all should be different integer numbers from 1 to 9. This means they must be numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, not necessarily in that order. There are 9!=362880 different orderings of these numbers. You are checking 9^9=387420489 combinations, more than 1000 times more than needed.

Comment: I am not a native speaker and it is quite hard to read such a text mash!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @n.m. in the comments, since all your variables must be different, you are looking for permutations<sup>1</sup> of the range 1 to 9. Which is great since c++ already provides you with [`std::next_permutation`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) that will generate permutations for you:

```
// Array for your variables, vars[0] is a, vars[1] is b, and so on...
std::array<int, 9> vars;

// Fill the array from number from 1 to 9 (so a = 1, b = 2, and so on... )
std::iota(std::begin(vars), std::end(vars), 1);

// Loop through all permutations of this array (see std::next_permutation):
//   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
//   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9 8
//   1 2 3 4 5 6 8 7 9
//   ...
//   9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
do {
    // Check if the variables matches what you want (see below for check):
    if (check(vars)) {
        std::cout << "Solution found: ";
        for (auto v: vars) 
            std::cout << v << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
} while(std::next_permutation(std::begin(vars), std::end(vars)));
```

Where `check` is, e.g.<sup>2</sup>:

```
int check(std::array<int, 9> const& vars) {
    // Remember that vars[0] is a, vars[1] is b, ..., I rewrote your comparison as:
    //   c * i * (a + d + 12 * e - f - 11 -10) + 13 * b * i + c * g * h == 66 * c * i
    // ...in order to avoid division.
    return vars[2] * vars[8] * (vars[0] + vars[3] + 12 * vars[4] - vars[5] - 11 - 10)
        + (13 * vars[1] * vars[8])
        + (vars[2] * vars[6] * vars[7]) == 66 * vars[2] * vars[8];
}
```

<sub><sup>1</sup> There are other ways to find your solution: You could reduce the domain of the next variable you are going to assign using the values of the already affected variables (e.g., there is no need to loop the last variable since there is only zero or one value possible at the end), but this is more complicated and probably overkill for what you want to do. If you want to learn more about this, you could look for [constraint programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_programming)</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> I re-organize the computation since you were doing integer division which truncates the result so you could get incorrect solution.</sub>

---

Some details about the code you may not be familiar with as a beginner:

- [`std::array<int, 9>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) (c++11) is a static array that replaces `int vars[9]`, you should prefer using this over c-style array whenever you can.
- [`std::iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) is a function from the `<algorithm>` header that will fill the range `std::begin(vars)` to `std::end(vars)` with increasing values starting at `1` (the value provided as the last argument).
- `for (auto x: vars)` is a [*range-based for loop*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) (available since c++11) which allows you to iterate over any container in a simple manner.